# Getting the rows returned by a subquery as columns of the original

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm making a database where students can register for workshops, and I have a table WorkshopRegistration that keeps the StudentID and WorkshopID.  My goal is to return a table with the columns StudentName, SchoolName, Workshop1, Workshop2.  Students will never be enrolled in more than 2 workshops.  I've gotten to the point of having 1 workshop as a column, but I'm having trouble getting the second one.

```
SELECT Students.StudentID, Students.name, Schools.name, 
      (SELECT Workshops.title
       FROM Workshops
       WHERE Workshops.WorkshopID IN
              (SELECT WorkshopID
               FROM WorkshopRegistration
               WHERE WorkshopRegistration.StudentID=Students.StudentID)) as Workshop1,
      (SELECT Workshops.title
       FROM Workshops
       WHERE Workshops.WorkshopID IN
              (SELECT WorkshopID
               FROM WorkshopRegistration
               WHERE WorkshopRegistration.StudentID=Students.StudentID)) as Workshop2
FROM Students, Schools
WHERE Students.SchoolID=Schools.SchoolID;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous solution will duplicate the workshop name, when a student only attends one workshop.  I would suggest instead:

```
SELECT students.studentid, 
       students.name, 
       schools.name, 
       mintitle AS Workshop1, 
       ( CASE 
           WHEN mintitle = maxtitle THEN NULL 
           ELSE maxtitle 
         END )  AS Workshop2 
FROM   students 
       JOIN school 
         ON students.schoolid = schools.schoolid 
       JOIN (SELECT studentid, 
                    Min(title) AS minTitle, 
                    Max(title) AS maxTitle 
             FROM   workshop w 
                    JOIN workshopregistration wr 
                      ON w.workshopid = wr.workshopid 
             GROUP  BY studentid) w 
         ON w.studentid = stuents.studentid
```

The case statement handles the situation where there is only one workshop.  Note, the same query will work even for no workshops by changing the second join to "LEFT OUTER JOIN".  To handle more than two workshops . . . well, that would take another question.

Comment: You are correct about the limitations of the previous query, though both of these suit my needs.  Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

I would change your query slightly, this will work as long as the student can only register for two workshops at the same time:

See this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69f45/1) with a working DEMO

```
SELECT t.StudentID
    , t.name as StudentName
    , s.name as SchoolName
    , ws1.Title as Workshop1
    , ws2.Title as Workshop2
FROM Students t
LEFT JOIN Schools s
    on t.SchoolID = s.SchoolID
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT max(WorkshopID) as WorkshopID, StudentId
    FROM WorkshopRegistration 
    GROUP BY studentid
) w1
    ON t.StudentID = w1.StudentID
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT min(WorkshopID) as WorkshopID, StudentId 
    FROM WorkshopRegistration 
    GROUP BY studentid
) w2
    ON t.StudentID = w2.StudentID
LEFT JOIN workshops ws1
    ON w1.workshopid = ws1.workshopid
LEFT JOIN workshops ws2
    ON w2.workshopid = ws2.workshopid
ORDER BY t.StudentID
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: That works very well to accomplish what I want.  I am new to joins having only utilized simple queries, and the SQLFiddle tool you've shown me is quite awesome.  Thank you very much.

Comment: If you are new to joins there is a great article that can be used as a reference http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html  Keep it bookmarked. :)